# Xcode 7.3 auto-updates IB files, clusters git

Tags: xcode, git, xcode7, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I have an Xcode project with, of course, nib files and storyboards. It seems like since I have upgraded to Xcode 7.3, the nibs and storyboards keep automatically updating themselves, thus marking them as modified by git.

This behavior used to happen only when opening the file: Xcode would then update some metadata. But now **it seems to keep updating itself even if Xcode is not the active app**. More specifically, I can be in Terminal, type `> git status` and have the expected result of `> Your branch is up-to-date`. Then, a few seconds later, run `> git status` again and have `myStoryboard.storybard`as a modified file. Xcode was never active during that period.

How can I avoid this behavior? Is it something new in Xcode 7.3?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this behind-the-scenes auto-modification is exactly to prevent the annoying feature where opening the storyboard file modifies it (and marks it as "dirty"). This way, the storyboard file is *already* modified (and saved) *before* you get around to opening it.

All of this has something to do with coordinating between the storyboard and your code, which is a long-standing problem that goes all the way back to the days when Xcode and Interface Builder were two completely separate applications that knew nothing of one another. Xcode today is a forced meld between these two applications, and tries to do all kinds of cute things behind the scenes so that they *do* know something about one another. What you're seeing is, I'm betting, a consequence of this.

Comment: I didn't use git at the time when InterfaceBuilder was a separate app, I was still learning... Your explanation makes sense, but is there any way around it? It only does it for nibs I opened since updating Xcode...

Comment: "is there any way around it?" No. File a bug report (which will probably come back as a duplicate, but it's still worth doing, as this puts the pressure on Apple).

Comment: I just submit a bug report as per your suggestion. We'll see! Thanks for the answer.